# OData server side enforced $expand filter parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a data model where a user might have permission to view a Person, and view notes on that person with status 1 but not status 2.

For the NotesController, we can filter out all results coming back with status 2 to enforce this permission. On the PersonsController however, if they expand the navigation property we want to enforce this as well.

How would this be done?

Various related questions I've come across have answers showing how to filter certain entity types, or hide certain properties, but what I need to do is add a server side enforced filter to expanded navigation properties.

I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.OData version 5.9.1.